# How to setup an array with objects that fall

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game and I want to be able to randomly generate enemies that fall from the sky and when the player comes in contact with them, the game will end. Except I don't know how to have objects randomly generated into an array so that I can set them to fall from above.

The file for the falling enemies is called orisaSprite.png.

My code can be found below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var canvas, ctx;

            var soldier=new Image();
            soldier.src="soldierSprite.png";

            var background=new Image();
            background.src="overwatchBackground.jpg";

            var soldierX, soldierY, soldierXFrame, soldierYFrame, soldierFrameW, soldierFrameH;

            var upKey, downKey, leftKey, rightKey;

            function initialize(){
                //canvas variables
                canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

                //soldier variables
                soldierX=0;
                soldierY=650;
                soldierXFrame=0;
                soldierYFrame=1;
                soldierFrameW=80;
                soldierFrameH=63;

                //keyboard controls
                upKey=false;
                downKey=false;
                leftKey=false;
                rightKey=false;
                document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
                document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler);

                update();
            }
            function update(){
                if(rightKey && soldierX<canvas.width-soldierFrameW-15) {
                    soldierYFrame=0;
                    soldierX += 6;
                }
                else if(leftKey && soldierX>0) {
                    soldierYFrame=1;
                    soldierX -= 6;
                }
                if(rightKey || leftKey || upKey || downKey){
                    soldierXFrame++;
                    soldierXFrame%=6;
                }
                draw();
                requestAnimationFrame(update);

            }
            function draw(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(soldier, soldierXFrame*soldierFrameW, soldierYFrame*soldierFrameH, soldierFrameW, soldierFrameH, soldierX, soldierY, soldierFrameW, soldierFrameH );
            }
            function keyDownHandler(e){
                //alert(e.keyCode);
                switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 37: leftKey=true; break;
                    case 39: rightKey=true; break;
                }
            }
            function keyUpHandler(e){
                //alert(e.keyCode);
                switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 37: leftKey=false; break;
                    case 39: rightKey=false; break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='initialize()'>
        <canvas id='myCanvas' width='1280px' height='800px'></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you upload your sprites and background to imgur so we can run your code? better yet, make a jsfiddle/codepen?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very specific question.
One way to get something to "fall" would be very similar to how you're rendering your soldier on the screen.
Simply render an object at the top of the screen, just like you do your soldier.
Instead of allowing it to move left, right, up, based on keyboard input, make it just move down.

Your question will likely get flagged as being too specific/not a good question.

Comment: "Your question will likely get flagged as being too specific/not a good question." - if you really believe that then why did you answer it?

Comment: in case I'm wrong about that since I'm relatively new to stack overflow